# Space Ship Move Left and right side but its not stop (stable or like vibrate) in the corner

Tags: unity, c#

[image]I made the game space shooter. In my space shooter its move left and right but not stop in the corner( Stable or vibrate). I don't know how it will be stopped.

Player Movement. cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speedMove = 3;
    public float bonusTime;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float _limit = 0;

    // 1 for right and -1 for left.
    private float _direction = 1;

    // You can call it as speed
    private float _speed = 0.01f;

    private bool toLeft = true;
    private bool toRight = true;

    public GameObject shield;
    public GUIText bonustimeText;

    private bool counting = true;
    private float counter;

    private Weapon[] addWeapons;

    public Sprite strongShip;
    public Sprite normalSprite;
    public Sprite shieldSprite;

    private SpriteRenderer sRender;
    private Weapon weaponScript;

    void Start () {

        counter = bonusTime;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        sRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        addWeapons = GetComponentsInChildren<Weapon> ();
        foreach (Weapon addWeapon in addWeapons) {
            addWeapon.enabled = false;
        }

        weaponScript = GetComponent<Weapon>();
        weaponScript.enabled = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x + _direction, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), _speed);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
            _direction *= -1;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "StrongMode") {
            Destroy (coll.gameObject);
            counting = true;
            StrongMode();
            Invoke ("Downgrade", bonusTime);
        }


        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "ShieldMode") {
            Destroy (coll.gameObject);
            counting = true;
            ShieldMode();
            Invoke("Downgrade", bonusTime);
        }

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Life") {
            GUIHealth gui = GameObject.Find ("GUI").GetComponent<GUIHealth> ();
            gui.AddHealth();
            SendMessage("AddHp");
            SoundHelper.instanceSound.PickUpSound();
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
        }

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
            SendMessage("Dead");
        }
    }

    void Downgrade()
    {
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.BonusDownSound ();
        counting = false;
        bonustimeText.text = "";
        counter = bonusTime;

        sRender.sprite = normalSprite;
        weaponScript.enabled = true;
        foreach (Weapon addWeapon in addWeapons) {
            addWeapon.enabled = false;
        }
        weaponScript.enabled = true;
        shield.SetActive (false);
    }


    void StrongMode()
    {
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.BonusUpSound ();
        sRender.sprite = strongShip;
        foreach (Weapon addWeapon in addWeapons) {
            addWeapon.enabled = true;
        }
        weaponScript.enabled = false;
    }


    void ShieldMode()
    {
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.BonusUpSound ();
        sRender.sprite = shieldSprite;
        shield.SetActive (true);
    }


//  void OnDestroy()
//  {
//      bonustimeText.text = "";
//  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you did not reset _direction and so it will always move to the right based on the Update function. You had a GetMouseButtonDown but it would just set _direction to be -1 so your spaceship will move left as it is now going in the negative x axis.

I think what you need is a way to set _direction to be 0 to stop it from moving.